# Functional derivative of a Green function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, greens-functions, functional-derivatives

I'm trying to prove that, given the Hamiltonian $\hat{H} + \int d\mathbf{x} \hat{n}(\mathbf{x})\varphi(\mathbf{x}, t)$, where $\varphi(\mathbf{x}, t)$ is some external field and $\hat{S}$ the scattering operator,
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)} \frac{< E | T \hat{S}\hat{O}_1...\hat{O}_N| E>}{<E|\hat{S}|E>} =  \frac{1}{i \hbar} \frac{< E | T \hat{S} \delta \hat{n}(x)\hat{O}_1...\hat{O}_N| E>}{<E|\hat{S}|E>}$$
where the operators evolve with $\hat{H}$, with ground state $|E>$.
I started with the definition of functional derivative:
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)}\frac{< E | T \hat{S}\hat{O}_1...\hat{O}_N| E>}{<E|\hat{S}|E>} = \frac{< E | T \frac{\delta\hat{S}}{\delta \varphi(x)}\hat{O}_1...\hat{O}_N| E> <E|\hat{S}|E> - < E | T \hat{S}\hat{O}_1...\hat{O}_N| E> <E|\frac{\delta\hat{S}}{\delta \varphi(x)}|E>  }{<E|\hat{S}|E>^2}$$
Then I tried to compute $<E|\frac{\delta\hat{S}}{\delta \varphi(x)}|E>$ writing the Texp expansion: in this way, the functional derivative cancels
a space-time integral out and the Texp looses a term. So I obtain $\frac{1}{i\hbar}<E|\hat{S} \hat{n}(\mathbf{x})|E>$.
Now, if $<E|\hat{S} \hat{n}(\mathbf{x})|E> = <E|\hat{S}|E><E|\hat{n}(\mathbf{x})|E>$, then I have the proof. The problem is that I don't know if this holds.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively.

Comment: Since $|E\rangle$ is the ground state, you may argue that $\hat{n}(\mathbf{x})|E\rangle = 0$, so that the second term vanishes and you are left with the first one, which is precisely what you aim to obtain.